# Unexpected identifier error jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with a line of code in jQuery. I have already solved the Uncaught SyntaxError: UnExpected String. Now I'm getting another error

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: UnExpected Identifier
```

For this line of code:

```
row += '<input type='text' name='fname' value="" class='fedit' />\n';
```

I have read through some other answers for this but I was not able to solve it for my problem.

Comment: You'll need to escape the quotations that are meant to be included in the string value. Or use different types of quotations to delimit the JavaScript and HTML strings. Currently, JavaScript understands the string to be just `'<input type='`. And, the `text` that follows isn't valid.

Comment: geesh...can even see the problem in the syntax highlighting where you just posted the code. There are numerous linting tools, both in IDE's and online you can use to check for syntax problems. Please use them as your first line of debugging rather than posting the code here

Comment: @charlietfl thanks too, but I never knew about linting as I'm still new to this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape your quotes. What's happening is that the compiler thinks your string has ended once you've added the `'` to avoid this escape your string using `\` such as `\'` this allows you to type `'Foo\'s Bar'`

**Code**

```
row += '<input type=\'text\' name=\'fname\' value="" class=\'fedit\' />\n';
```

**Details**
The compiler sees a few parts

> String: `'<input type='`
>
> Code: `text`
>
> String:  `'name='`
>
> Code: `fname`
>
> String: `'value="" class='`
>
> Code: `fedit`
>
> String:  `'/>\n'`

The newline *(`\n`)* is unnecessary because HTML strings don't need them, you might want to put a `<br/>` instead.

Answer (score 1):

try `row += "<input type='text' name='fname' value='' class='fedit' />\n";`
you're mixing single and doble quotes

Answer (score 1):

Try `row += '<input type="text" name="fname" value="" class="fedit" />\n';`

The quotes were conflicting